# Copy file into specific directory in java

Tags: java, file, nio

Below is the code for copy a file from one directory to another directory.
For eg: if the filename is Red-Already over,Red-Already Over(slow),NEFFEX-Destiny,then it should create a directory name red and copy the file into it,
For another artist it should NEFFEX folder and copy the file into it.

The problem is that it can create the directory if Files.copy is commented.But it is unable to create a dir but copy the file when Files.copy is uncommented.
The file is not playable because it doesn't have extension(seems the file is not getting copied properly).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class OrgLogic {

String path="C:\\Users\\Fawkes\\Music\\Music\\";
String target_path="C:\\Output\\";

OrgLogic() throws IOException{
    File f=new File(path); //loads the input dir path
    File dir=new File(target_path); //loads the output dir path
    dir.mkdir();//create a new dir name output
    File[] total_file=f.listFiles();//get the total number of file
    //System.out.println(total_file.length);//prints the total number of the file
    for(int i=0;i<total_file.length;i++) {
        String name=total_file[i].getName();
        String new_name=name.substring(0, name.indexOf("-")-1);
        dir=new File(target_path+new_name);
        if(dir.exists()) {
            //new File(new_path+new_name).mkdir();
            Files.copy(total_file[i].toPath(), dir.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
        else {
            //new File(target_path+new_name).mkdir();
            dir.mkdir();
            Files.copy(total_file[i].toPath(), dir.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        }
    }   

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new OrgLogic();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

 }
```

The filename path is:
Source:
C:\Users\Fawkes\Music\Music\Red-Already over
C:\Users\Fawkes\Music\Music\Red-Already over(slow)
C:\Users\Fawkes\Music\Music\NEFFEX-Destiny

Destination:
C:\Output\

For eg:
C:\Output\Red\Already over
C:\Output\Red\Already over(slow)
C:\Output\NEFFEX\Destiny

it is declared as variable:path and target_path

(Feature: it would be good that while pasting codes in here **Line Number** should be there.)

Comment: Your description doesn’t make sense to me. The filesnames you cited have no path separator. I’m assuming you don’t have unit tests to show us what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: File[] total_file=f.listFiles();//get the total number of file
This line loads all the file in that dir,I debugged it and i saw it.

The filesnames you cited have no path separator--->i am unable to understand waht you exactly meant?

Comment: "Red-Already over,Red-Already Over(slow),NEFFEX-Destiny" doesn't look much like a filename. What is the absolute path to and from?

Comment: If the problem is that it is unable to create a directory, replace dir.mkdir() with `Files.createDirectory(dir.toPath())`, which will always either succeed, or throw an IOException.  In fact, you should not be using the File class at all, as it is obsolete, for exactly this reason:  many methods of File don’t report errors properly.  Use Path and Files instead.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The filename path is:
Source:
C:\\Users\\Fawkes\\Music\\Music\\Red-Already over
C:\\Users\\Fawkes\\Music\\Music\\Red-Already over(slow)
C:\\Users\\Fawkes\\Music\\Music\\NEFFEX-Destiny

Destination:
C:\\Output\\

For eg:
C:\\Output\\Red\\Already over
C:\\Output\\Red\\Already over(slow)
C:\\Output\\NEFFEX\\Destiny

it is declared as variable:path and target_path

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class OrgLogic {

String path="C:\\Users\\Fawkes\\Music\\Music\\";
String target_path="C:\\Output\\";

OrgLogic() throws IOException{
    File f=new File(path); //loads the input dir path
    File dir=new File(target_path); //loads the output dir path
    dir.mkdir();//create a new dir name output
    File[] total_file=f.listFiles();//get the total number of file
    //System.out.println(total_file.length);//prints the total number of the file
    for(int i=0;i<total_file.length;i++) {
        String name=total_file[i].getName();
        String new_name=name.substring(0, name.indexOf("-")-1);
        dir=new File(target_path+new_name);
        if(dir.exists()) {
            Path src=Paths.get(total_file[i].getPath());
            Path dest=Paths.get(dir.getAbsolutePath().concat("\\").concat(total_file[i].getName()));
            Files.copy(src, dest ,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            System.out.println("Files copied: "+(i+1)+"/"+total_file.length);
        }
        else {
            dir.mkdir();    
            Path src=Paths.get(total_file[i].getPath());
            Path dest=Paths.get(dir.getAbsolutePath().concat("\\").concat(total_file[i].getName()));// only needed to add this line.
            Files.copy(src, dest ,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);             
            System.out.println("Files copied: "+(i+1)+"/"+total_file.length);
        }
    }   


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new OrgLogic();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```